# Unreal engine c++ write delegate OnScreenshotCaptured

Tags: c++, delegates, unreal-engine4

I am new to C++. I've wrote code in C# and PHP.Since I am using Unreal engine I am trying to learn C++. For my project I need to make a screenshot in-game and show it immediately so I want to get it as a texture.

I made a blueprint node which calls this function i've made:

```
void UMyBlueprintFunctionLibrary::TakeScreenshot()
{
    FScreenshotRequest::RequestScreenshot(true);

    if (GEngine)
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Red, "Tried to take screenshot");
}
```

When I hover my mouse above RequestScreenshot I see the following pop-up:

"Screenshot can be read from memory by subscribing to the viewsport OnScreenshopCaptured delegate"

So that is what I try to do but I have no idea how I looked up this:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UGameViewportClient/OnScreenshotCaptured/

Can someone tell me how to implement this and how you see/know how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative, no delegate, but `FRenderTarget::ReadPixel()` to some buffer you allocated, by implementing your own `UGameViewportClient` (inherit it), and overriding `Draw()` function.

I'll show the essential codes, but not complete.

```
void UMyGameViewportClient::Draw(FViewport* Viewport, FCanvas* SceneCanvas)
{
    Super::Draw(Viewport, SceneCanvas);
    if (any_condition_you_need) {
        CaptureFrame();
    }
}

void UMyGameViewportClient::CaptureFrame()
{
    if (!Viewport) {
        return;
    }

    if (ViewportSize.X == 0 || ViewportSize.Y == 0) {
        return;
    }

    ColorBuffer.Empty();  // Declare this in header as TArray<FColor> 

    if (!Viewport->ReadPixels(ColorBuffer, FReadSurfaceDataFlags(),
                          FIntRect(0, 0, ViewportSize.X, ViewportSize.Y)))
    {
        return;
    }
    SaveThumbnailImage();
}

void UMyGameViewportClient::SaveThumbnailImage()
{
    IImageWrapperModule& wrappermodule = FModuleManager::LoadModuleChecked<IImageWrapperModule>(FName("ImageWrapper"));
    auto wrapper_ptr = wrappermodule.CreateImageWrapper(EImageFormat::PNG);
    for (int i = 0; i < ColorBuffer.Num(); i++)
    {
        auto ptr = &ColorBuffer[i];
        auto r = ptr->R;
        auto b = ptr->B;
        ptr->R = b;
        ptr->B = r;
        ptr->A = 255;
    } // not necessary, if you like bgra, just change the following function argument to ERGBFormat::BGRA
    wrapper_ptr->SetRaw(&ColorBuffer[0], ColorBuffer.Num() * 4,
       ViewportSize.X, ViewportSize.Y, ERGBFormat::RGBA, 8);
    FFileHelper::SaveArrayToFile(wrapper_ptr->GetCompressed(), *ThumbnailFile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at it in a moment

Comment: Hmm i really need to describe to a delegate